# Basic question with coprimes and modulos

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I started reading about Modular Arithmetic and solving some random basic exercises, and this one appeared:

"Find an integer number $a$ such that any $b$ coprime with 34 is congruent to $a^k \mod34$ with $k \ge 0$"

I have no clue on how to solve this question, can anyone help me please?

Comment: **Hint** $a$ has to be coprime to $34$ as well.  Just try all powers of all coprime $a$ and see which one generates all coprime $b$.

Comment: This is about [*primitive roots*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n). You need to find a number $a$ such that the powers of $a$ cycle through all the coprime residue classes mod $34$. A good start would be to establish how many such values there are (which is [denoted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) as $\phi(34)$)

Comment: Explicit, clearly what $k$ is, please.Is it any integer?

Comment: @Piquito it should say "for some $k \in \mathbb N$"

Comment: Sorry for the non explicit $k$ guys, and thanks for the hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb Z/34\mathbb Z$ has as zero divisors the multiples of $2$ and $17$ and the group of the invertible elements is
$$(\mathbb Z/34\mathbb Z)^*=\{3,9,27,13,5,15,11,33,31,25,7,21,29,19,23,1\}$$  Taking a primitive root modulo $34$ you have $a^k=b$ for $k=1,2,3,....,16$ giving the $16$ elements of $(\mathbb Z/34\mathbb Z)^*$

On the other hand there are several primitive roots modulo $34$ (eight in total,$3,5,7,11,23,27,29,31$). We have used the p. r. $3$ to represent in the same order above the following way $$(\mathbb Z/34\mathbb Z)^*=\{3,3^2,3^3,3^4,3^5,3^6,3^7,3^8,3^9,3^{10},3^{11},3^{12},3^{13},3^{14},3^{15},3^{16}\}$$
Hence $a=3$ is a solution to the problem and the other possible solutions are the other primitive root modulo $34$ which are  $5,7,11,23,27,29$ and $31$.